# problems while trying to make a text editor

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here i am trying to make a text editor which has two characteristics.

> 1. It will increase size with the increasing amount of text .
>
> 2.It can be pulled up or down with mouse( i haven't implemented it yet,so it is out of question now)

I have put a down side indicator image at the bottom of the editor div.
problem is:

> 1.When text reaches at the bottom it interacts with the indicator image.I want it in such a way so that,when text reaches a sudden point
>   above the indicator image it will expand downward.
>
> 2.indicator image comes after i enter a character in the editor.I want it to appear from the beginnning.
>
> 3.There is an issue with ENTER key.The text pointer comes to the image and new line is added with the second enter.

That's the overall situation.I tried my best to explain the problems.How can i fix this ? If there is any better way to do this please let me know.

```css
    #editor{
      position:relative;
      width:400px;
   height:auto;
   border:1px solid black;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   padding-left:4px;
   padding-right:4px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   overflow-y:scroll;
   }
```

```html
<div id='editor' contenteditable='true' ><img src='http://s22.postimg.org/rh9bx9a3h/ind.png?noCache=1437598902' style='position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:200px;cursor:n-resize;'/> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div id='editor' contenteditable='true' ></div>
```

CSS:

```
#editor{
     position:relative;
     width:400px;
     height:auto;
     border:1px solid black;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     padding-left:4px;
     padding-right:4px;
     padding-bottom: 1em;
     box-sizing:border-box;
     overflow-y:scroll;
     line-height: 1em;
     background: no-repeat center bottom url("http://s22.postimg.org/rh9bx9a3h/ind.png?noCache=1437598902");
  }
```

Take a look at it in action with this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v4nwgcot/

Comment: thanks ,look okay.Can you explain a little about the changes and why they work ?

Comment: Absolutely.  I added a 1em padding to the bottom of the text box (1 em is the height of your current font size) to keep the arrow below the text.  That fixed problem 1.  I couldn't recreate your second problem.  I changed your image tag to a background image in CSS so that it is no longer a DOM element, which was causing your third problem.

Comment: i have one question..if the image  is not an element anymore then how can i be able to grab it to pull down or up?

Comment: There are many ways you could accomplish this, all of which (I believe) require some javascript.  You should open a new question for that.